# is there any vb msgbox alternative in c# web application work on ashx?

Tags: c#, asp.net

as i start c#, i find that c# (web application) doesn't support msgbox or something like that.
in vb web application i could use msgbox, it doesn't work when deploy, but help me for debugging.

as i searched web there is some solution like:

```
string message = "Hello! Mudassar.";
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>");
sb.Append("window.onload=function(){");
sb.Append("alert('");
sb.Append(message);
sb.Append("')};");
sb.Append("</script>");
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString());
```

but it doesn't work in ashx handlers.
is there any vb msgbox alternative in c#:

1- work at least before deploy.
2- work in ashx handlers too.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do debugging you can use Tracing and Debugging features avaialble within ASP .Net please read the following article for detail http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386420.ASPX

Comment: i add using System.Windows.Forms; then add in references, so now i can use messagebox, is it wrong? at least before deploy? tracing was great but it is more simple. i must work on trace more.

Comment: This is not a good approach anyway, regardless it works or not, though i am sure it will not work. Spend some time with tracing and debugging  you will get use to it.

Comment: as i am beginner in c# this method works and helps me very much, but you are right. thanks.